# Interceptar constructors e destructors de todos os objetos em Delphi

Tags: delphi

Eu uso um recurso em meu sistema onde alguns usuários podem ter acesso a uso de *scripts* em Pascal `Object` e podem personalizar algumas regras.

Isso está gerando um certo problema de *Memory Leak*, pois assim como um desenvolvedor pode esquecer de destruir um objeto o usuário pode fazer o mesmo neste recurso, portanto eu estou precisando criar um controle de *Memory Leak* bem simples e leve, onde o usuário vai saber que criou um objeto porém não o destruiu.

O problema que estou enfrentando é interceptar o `TComponent` no *constructor* e *destructor* para monitorar os objetos criados e destruídos.

Tentei das formas a baixo:

```
TComponent = class helper for System.Classes.TComponent
protected
  constructor Create;
  destructor Destroy; // Aqui ocorre um erro ao compilar;
end;
```

ou

```
TComponent = class(System.Classes.TComponent)
protected
  constructor Create; override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;
```

Neste caso nem sempre passa, pois tenho que por no uses de todas as *units*.

Alguém tem alguma solução ou dica?

Agradeço antecipadamente.

Comment: O ideal seria você criar uma classe base do tipo Genérica com implementação de Interface. Dessa forma próprio Delphi tomaria conta da demanda. No Delphi o ARC controla o memory leak sozinho, mas apenas para Interface.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica.
Vou fazer umas pesquisas e caso tenha sucesso, postarei aqui.

Porém se mais alguém desejar se pronunciar, serei grato.

Answer (score -2):

Creio que a sintaxe é essa:

```
TComponent = class helper for System.Classes.TComponent
protected
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;
```

Será necessário incluir a unit antes de Classes na cláusula uses.

Comment: Obrigado pelo apoio Ricardo;
Esta sintaxe também já tentei em outro momento, porém tenho um retorno de erro. "E2295 A class helper cannot introduce a destructor".

Não usado o Helper, o resultado se aproxima do que precisamos, mas é necessário por a unit logo após o classes em todas as units e isso não é seguro pois a equipe é grande e alguém pode esquecer de incluir.